# screen not working properly on my tablet

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, tablet, screen

I have a brand new 10.1 inch tablet, made in china. The screen doesn't respond to touch as much as it should, a few other little things and I can't work out some of the onscreen operating icon/button things. The resellers suggested I start with Android Central Forums, as this is the only Android devise they sell so they don't know the answers. I joined up with A.C.Forums, but can't work out how to post. Help and/or advice would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange! The question-and-answer format of this site works best if you ask a single, specific question in each question post. I've taken the liberty of answering the question from your title; if you have further questions about particular icons or buttons, ask a new question for each one, explaining what you have trouble with.

Comment: So, your question for the Android Enthusiests Stack Exchange forum is "How do I post a question on Android Central Forums"? I think that is out of scope on this site.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I think wot yr saying is that asking how to operate within the ac forums, isn't a question for the android site. I agree, didn't think of it at the time. Was too stressed at the time, feeling that I can't get any help if I can't post. I'll have a look around to see wot I can find. Ta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an easy way to check if the tablet has a faulty touchscreen. Go into Google Play and install a painting app. There are many free painting apps to choose from: just pick a simple one. Run the app and try to paint the whole screen. If the painting doesn't follow your finger, or any parts of the screen can't be painted, you can see the screen is faulty, and you should return it to the seller for a refund or exchange. Faulty touchscreens are quite common on cheap Chinese imports because they use cheaper components and don't test them thoroughly.

The other possibility is that, being a cheap tablet, it has an old-fashioned *resistive* touchscreen instead of a proper *capacitive* one. You can tell by using a pointy plastic stylus (such as the handle end of a toothbrush, or the non-writing end of a ballpoint pen) to click on something on the screen. If that works, it's a resistive screen, not a capacitive one.

You'll find any swipe gestures a lot harder to perform on a resistive screen, and multi-touch gestures like pinch-to-zoom are not possible at all. You'll find a resistive touchscreen is a lot more responsive to being pressed with your fingernail instead of the flat 'pad' of your finger.

Comment: Thanks Dan for that. I'll check that out. And good point, one question per post  :-\

Comment: Thanks Dan, I checked both suggestions. The painting covered the entire screen. I checked the screen with a pen end and (as I thought) it definately has the capacitive screen (thank goodness). Also by the time I had done that, the screen has worked perfectly lol.

Comment: OK, I'm glad it's working for you now. If you're still having trouble working out what any icons or buttons do, you know where the Ask Question button is!